# Solving second order time-dependent PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve a non-linear second order `PDE` as given below.
$$\partial_{t}u+u\partial_{x}u=\partial_{xx}u+u$$
with periodic boundary condition: $$u(x,t)=u(x+2\pi,t)$$ and initial condition: $$u(x,0)=u_{0}(x)$$
I am using a fractional step method to solve this problem as shown below.

- 1st step: Non-linear part $$\partial_{t}u=-u\partial_{x}u$$
- 2nd step: Linear part $$\partial_{t}u=\partial_{xx}u+u$$
  using Fourier discretization in space.

But I do not get reasonable results and there are oscillations.
Any suggestions for any other method for solving such `PDEs`?

Comment: Why not just [method of lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_lines) in direction $t$?

Comment: Also, the Cauchy problem for this PDE doesn't seem always very well posed. I suspect you get only local existence in time.

Comment: Consider for instance the simpler $\partial_t u = u(1-\partial_t u)$. If $\partial_tu>-1$, then solutions try to grow exponentially and then I don't know if your PDE blows up...

Comment: If your PDE is not well behaved, no matter how good a numerical scheme you pick, it will never avoid blow-ups

Comment: You are asking if there is one of the members who can solve the $1$-D Navier-Stokes equation...

Comment: Try using implicit methods if you are getting instability. Like the other users mentioned, this can only help so much since you only have local-well posedness

Comment: Recipe: For the Burgers-type part, implement the [Lax-Friedrichs method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method) for nonlinear problems. For the linear part, implement one classical [finite-difference method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Example:_The_heat_equation) for the heat equation. Choose the time step in such a way that both steps are stable.

Comment: Since this is a periodic boundary condition, I was trying to use Fourier series but that does not work too. Any suggestions?